# Get intraday data of SAP with google Finance

Tags: data, intraday

According to this [link](http://girirajcollections.blogspot.de/2011/03/google-realtime-intraday-data.html) I try to get intraday data of SAP listed at Xetra.

Intraday data with timestep of 1 second would be great. I do not understand parts of the command, I try

http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=SAP&x=ETR&i=60&p=5d&f=d,c,o,h,l&df=cpct&auto=1&ts=1266701290218

Now, first thing I ask myself: Why is there a date column (COLUMNS=DATE,CLOSE,HIGH,LOW,OPEN)? I mean, since this is intraday data of 5 days, there should be more rows per day than just one?

How can I get intraday data of SAP at Xetra of the last 10 years with this command?

Comment: is this time delayed?

Answer (score 3):

The data is numbered by order in the date column. Its not a real timestamp, to find the actual time, you need to look at the header, where the exact time where the data starts is noted.

For 1 second intervals, change the i-flag in the URL to 1, like here:

https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=SAP&x=ETR&i=1&f=d,c,o,h,l&df=cpct&auto=1&ts=1266701290218

I also removed the period-flag (p) which was previously limiting the request to the last five days. This should provide you with all data thats available on a one second interval, but if you play around with the p-flag a little, you may be able to find more. Alternatively try to mess with the ts-flag, which would supply a start date.